# Passing a function to a wrapped React component in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, react-dropzone

I'm trying to use the package `react-dropzone` in clojurescript.

The original javascipt code has a function as the child of a wrapped component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

<Dropzone onDrop={acceptedFiles => console.log(acceptedFiles)}>
  {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
    <section>
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  )}
</Dropzone>
```

I have tried converting it to this:

```
(ns test.dropzone
  (:require ["react" :as react]
            ["react-dropzone" :default Dropzone]))


(defn file-dropzone []
  [:> Dropzone {:on-drop #(js/alert "Drop")}
   (fn [getRootProps getInputProps]
     [:section
      [:div
       [:p "Drop"]]])])
```

but it returns this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ns, name, fqn, _hash, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Dropzone (created by grafitch.dropzone.file_dropzone)
    in grafitch.dropzone.file_dropzone (created by upload-test-page)
    in div (created by upload-test-page)
    in div (created by upload-test-page)
    in div (created by upload-test-page)
    in section (created by upload-test-page)
    in upload-test-page (created by page)
    in div (created by page)
    in page
```

How can this be done in clojurescript?

Comment: The error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child` happens because you're including a Clojure function (eg. `(fn...)`)  as a child of the `DropZone` react class, which is not valid. I think you need to construct the DropZone object instance in a different way (probably with `useDropzone()`), then use `getRootProps` and `getInputProps` that you can pass as properties of a `[:div ...` or `[:input ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [helix](https://github.com/Lokeh/helix) to translate the react code to clojurescript. I could not figure out how to use reagent to do this.

**Solution**:

```
(ns test.dropzone
  (:require
   [helix.core :refer [defnc $]]
   [helix.dom :as d]
   ["react-dropzone" :as dz :default Dropzone :refer [useDropzone]]))


(defnc file-dropzone []
  ($ Dropzone {:onDrop (fn [accepted-files] (.log js/console accepted-files))}
     (fn [dropzone-obj]
       (let [[getRootProps getInputProps]
             (as-> dropzone-obj obj [(.-getRootProps obj) (.-getInputProps obj)])]
         (d/section
          (d/div {:& (getRootProps)}
                 (d/input {:& (getInputProps)})
                 (d/p "Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files")))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you are getting this error is because the result of your inner function is actually a PersistentVector not a react component. Wrap the result of the function with a reagent.core/as-element.

Answer (score 0):

I almost managed to do this with the reagent.

```
(ns test.dropzone
  (:require
   ["react-dropzone" :refer [useDropzone]]))

(defn dropzone []
  (let [props (useDropzone)
        get-input-props (.-getInputProps props)
        get-root-props (.-getRootProps props)]
    
    (r/as-element
     [:section.container
      [:div.dropzone (js->clj (get-root-props #_(clj->js {:onClick #(js/alert "Click")})) :keywordize-keys true)
       [:input (js->clj (get-input-props) :keywordize-keys true)]
       [:p "my dropzone"]]])))
```

And calling it by

```
[:> dropzone]
```

But seems like there are some still some problems with ref.

it works when I add some own onClick or onDrop actions (like in commented section), but without it, nothing happens on click or drop.